# How to set up SSH access without a valid internet IP?

Tags: macos, ssh, ip, remote-access

I want to allow other people to ssh into my Mac via login and password, but it does not have a valid internet IP.

How to allow people to ssh when the machine might be at home, in an office, or coffee shop?

Answer (score 2):

You need a valid IP somewhere.
If this IP is not static, you can advertise it through dyn.com as suggested by other answer.

Behind the valid IP :
you'll need a computer to run a VPN server.

On your Mac :
connect (automatically ?) to the VPN, so that other peoples will be able to "see" you.

For other people to connect :
They'll need an access to the VPN server, addressing it through its static IP or its dyn.com hostname.
Then they can connect to your ssh.

This won't be easy to set-up, but I don't see another answer.
Advertising the IP of your Mac won't be enough because this will just allow other people to see the IP of the router which grants you internet access. But this router will not forward its ssh port 22 to yours.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a service like [dyn.com](http://dyn.com/) or [afraid.org](http://freedns.afraid.org) to provide a dynamic DNS name to the IP address your laptop gets. Many of these services offer a client program to update the dynamic DNS listing when the computer gets a new public-facing IP address (such as when your home internet IP lease refreshes)

Answer (score 0):

And here it comes a much simpler solution:
http://sf.net/p/pigterm
I just released this opensource project which:
Helps you connect to your Linux terminal far away without Valid IP, VPN, dyn.com account, etc. All you need to have is a pair of Jabber chatting accounts. You run the software in your Linux server, it connects using its jabber account and waits for you. You run the software again at home with another jabber account and start chatting with your server. Two computers will see each other and will start communicating. All the communications are encrypted.
This image here shows more detail on how:
http://sourceforge.net/p/pigterm/wiki/PigTerm%20Home/attachment/Howitworks.png